# How to access character (physics type) via python to update it's jump force in real time?

Tags: python, game-engine

I would like to know if it's possible to access the jump speed via python to set different values for it. (.game.jump_speed / GameObjectSettings.jump_speed).

Is there a python script sample somewhere?

Here is a practical example to illustrate this question:

Let's say you have two types of platforms: Red and Blue. 
When one collides with the red platform this event triggers a jump force of 10.00 (ten). 
When one collides with the blue platform this event triggers a jump force of 20.00 (twenty).

[image: pic]

[image]

There is a .blend for prototyping here (google drive, saved in Blender version 2.78c):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byr4NYScNOlRMkkwWGx5VG5ETEk/view?usp=sharing
(Controls: WASD to move the character).

[image]

Physics pannel:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Current api (2.78c) GameObjectSettings.jump_speed](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.GameObjectSettings.html?highlight=jump%20speed)

GameObjectSettings is part of **bpy** which **only work inside of blender** and only in Blender, this means that your game **using bpy and bge only will work inside Blender** because **bpy will not work in standalone** and you dont want that if you are making a game but if you are makin sortsof simulation and you will be using always blender then you can use bge and bpy.

You can access jump_speed:

```
from bpy import data

data.objects["Cube"].game.jump_speed = 50
print(data.objects["Cube"].game.jump_speed)
```

As soon as you run the script 50 will be the value for **jump force** in physics property panel:

[image]

[here you can found some (old) good bge python tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/user/goranmilovano)

If you want in game dinamically change the jump speed you can use the next script portion was extracted from one of the tutorials, thanks to Goran Milovanovic

**script**

```
from bge import logic
from mathutils import Vector
import math

class MoveWSAD:
    """
    Goran's 2.6x FPS base-frame

    2011 - Goran Milovanvic - nilunder.com

    """
    def __init__(self, cont, own):
        self.cont = cont
        self.body = own
        self.sen_key_w = self.cont.sensors["W"]
        self.sen_key_s = self.cont.sensors["S"]
        self.sen_key_a = self.cont.sensors["A"]
        self.sen_key_d = self.cont.sensors["D"]
        self.sen_key_space = self.cont.sensors["space"]
        self.sen_col_onground = self.cont.sensors["onground"]
        self.speed_ground = 4
        self.speed_jump = self.speed_ground * 0.8
        self.main = self._inAir

    def _getMoveVec(self):
        forward_back = self.sen_key_w.positive - self.sen_key_s.positive
        left_right = self.sen_key_d.positive - self.sen_key_a.positive
        velocity = Vector((left_right, forward_back, 0))
        return velocity

    def _onGround(self):
        vec_velocity = self._getMoveVec()
        vec_velocity.magnitude = self.speed_ground
        if self.sen_key_space.positive:
            vec_velocity.z = self.speed_jump
        self.body.setLinearVelocity(vec_velocity, 1)
        if not self.sen_col_onground.positive:
            self.main = self._inAir

    def _inAir(self):
        if self.sen_col_onground.positive:
            self.main = self._onGround

"""Strapicarus 2017"""                
class Player:       
    def __init__(self, cont, body):       
        self.body = body
        self.move_wsad = MoveWSAD(cont, body)
        self.main = self.walking

    def walking(self):
        if self.move_wsad.sen_key_space.positive:
             self.change_speed(1)
        self.move_wsad.main()


    def change_speed(self, speed):
        if self.move_wsad.speed_jump < 20:
            self.move_wsad.speed_jump += speed
        else:
            self.move_wsad.speed_jump = self.move_wsad.speed_ground * 0.8
        return

def main(cont):
    if not 'init' in cont.owner.getPropertyNames():
        cont.owner['player'] = Player(cont, cont.owner)
        cont.owner['init'] = True
    cont.owner['player'].main()

main(logic.getCurrentController())
```

**LogicBricks**

[image]

**Physics panel**

[image]

**EDIT ADDED**

Well a just download your blend and you put the right blend this time (i forgot to mention that before answer), and i test 
¿if i change the **loc z** in **motion actuator** the character will jump higher? and **YES** it works.

So you just need **increase the loc z value to set the jump speed for that motion actuator**:

[image]

And if you want a **python way** here is to:

**jump.py**

```
from bge import logic

def main(cont):
    jumpact = cont.actuators['jumpSpeed']
    colsen = cont.sensors['Blue']
    if not 'init' in cont.owner.getPropertyNames():
        cont.owner['init'] = True
        cont.owner['_onair'] = False
        cont.owner['jumpSpeed'] = 0.0
        print('init...')
        return   

    if not cont.owner['_onair'] and colsen.positive:
        if  cont.owner['jumpSpeed'] < 10.0:
            cont.owner['jumpSpeed'] += 1 
            jumpact.dLoc = (0,0,cont.owner['jumpSpeed'])
            print('adding jump speed')
            print(jumpact.dLoc.z)
        else:
            cont.owner['jumpSpeed'] = 0.0
        cont.activate(jumpact)
        cont.owner['_onair'] = True
        return
    else:
        cont.deactivate(jumpact)
        cont.owner['_onair'] = False
        return
#    print(dir(jumpact))
#    print(jumpact.force)
#    print(jumpact.linV)
#    print(jumpact.torque)
#    print(jumpact.dLoc) #FOUND IT ! xD

main(logic.getCurrentController())
```

**Logic editor**

[image]

**Blend file**

[image]

Comment: Dear Strapicarus, Thank you very much for your reply. But in my case I need a solution that works inside the Blender Game Engine (real time update) and with the "charachter" physics type. I also don't need other movements other than jump. The bounty prize is yours because of the effort. But I still consider this question without solution ;) Greetings! Ortiz

Comment: I think i found a solution check it in the edit.

Comment: Hi Strapicarus!

I tested your file in Blender 2.78c, but the jump is behaving like I'm using a simple motion value applied to a dynamic actor. The jump is not behaving like the charachter physics yet. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking for is not possible in Blender 2.78b.  We will need to recreate the jump functionality.

The jump pads will require a float property called ['jumpSpeed'] and collision enabled in its physics tab.  Static physics type should work.

The rest is explained below.

```
#if we put the python controler in modual mode,
#then it can pass the currentController as the first argument
def input(cont):
    #if you have problems with floating after a jump, then increse Max Fall Speed
    own = cont.owner

    #if were going to use the Characture Wrapper, then we need to get it first
    import bge
    pysOwn = bge.constraints.getCharacter(own)

    #this is how i handle keybinds
    clicked = bge.logic.keyboard.active_events
    click = {bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED, bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE}

    #if the KEY is not in active_events then dict.get() will return None
    forward = clicked.get(bge.events.WKEY)
    backward = clicked.get(bge.events.SKEY)
    leftward = clicked.get(bge.events.AKEY)
    rightward = clicked.get(bge.events.DKEY)
    spaceward = clicked.get(bge.events.SPACEKEY)

    #if the jump count is less then the max jumps then we can jump
    if spaceward == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED and own['jumpCount'] < pysOwn.maxJumps:
        #we can get a sensor even if its not connected to the current controller
        #it may have to be connected to at least one controller
        #if the collision sensor hits at least one object with the jumpSpeed property then we get it,
        #otherwise this get None
        hitObj = own.sensors['Collision'].hitObject
        #if theres a hitObj, then we use the jumpSpeed provided by that object,
        #otherwise we use the default on the char
        if hitObj:
            jumpSpeed = hitObj['jumpSpeed']
        else:
            jumpSpeed = own['jumpSpeed']

        #we move the char along the z axis by the jumpSpeed
        x = pysOwn.walkDirection.x
        y = pysOwn.walkDirection.y
        z = pysOwn.walkDirection.z + jumpSpeed
        pysOwn.walkDirection = (x,y,z)

        #this will trigger the property sensor, so we know when to stop jumping
        own['jumping'] = True
        #this sets the number of times we've jumped scence landind
        own['jumpCount'] += 1


    #if the char is on the ground or has the walkAir ablity then it can move, otherwise it can't
    if pysOwn.onGround or own['walkAir']:

        #we'r going to replace the current walkDirection with a new one
        x = 0
        y = 0
        z = pysOwn.walkDirection.z

        speed = own['walkSpeed']

        if forward in click:
            y += speed
        if backward in click:
            y -= speed
        if leftward in click:
            x -= speed
        if rightward in click:
            x += speed

        #this converts our local vector into a world vector
        from mathutils import Vector
        vec = Vector((x,y,z))
        vec = own.worldOrientation * vec

        #apply the walkDirection
        pysOwn.walkDirection = vec




def stopJump(cont):
    #this function asumes it will only be run if own['jumping'] == True
    own = cont.owner
    import bge
    pysOwn = bge.constraints.getCharacter(own)

    #if the char is on the ground, stop jumping and reset
    if pysOwn.onGround:
        pysOwn.walkDirection = (0,0,0)
        own['jumping'] = False
        own['jumpCount'] = 0
```

[image: logic]

Comment: Hello Otto!

Thank you for your time. I tried to apply your jump setup withouth sucess. I hosted my attempt here [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byr4NYScNOlRWFdibHJPTWZ6R2c/view?usp=sharing I don't know how I should trigger the jump. I confess that your python script is too advanced for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from bge import constraints

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner

character = constraints.getCharacter(owner)

# When colliding use:
character.gravity = value float

# Set a different value for each platform you want to change the height of the jump
```